# "Update" en java no actualiza los datos en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas,

Tengo un código que en teoría, me busca primero si el registro está ya incluido en la base de datos y si es así, me actualiza los datos, en caso contrario me lo incluye.

Sin embargo, los datos no se actualizan, tampoco me los vuelve a meter, es decir, entiendo que tengo algo mal en la ejecución del "UPDATE". Os dejo el código:

```
public Conectate(ArrayList<Item> games, final Map<String, String> countries) {    

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, pass);
        System.out.println("¡Conectado!");


        //CREAMOS LA TABLA
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info_XboxOne (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), "
                + "Juego_vinculado VARCHAR(500), Juego VARCHAR(500), Tipologia VARCHAR (500), Pertenece VARCHAR (500), "
                + "Nota VARCHAR (10), Descripcion_Ingles TEXT(4000), Descripcion_Castellano TEXT(4000), Pegi VARCHAR(10), Pegi_USA VARCHAR (30) , Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR(500), Codigo_juego VARCHAR (100),"
                + "Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Argentina VARCHAR (50), Argentina_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Argentina_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Brasil VARCHAR (50), Brasil_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Brasil_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Canada VARCHAR (50), Canada_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Canada_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Colombia VARCHAR (50), Colombia_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Colombia_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Espanya VARCHAR (50), Espanya_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Espanya_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "USA VARCHAR (50), USA_Oferta VARCHAR (50), USA_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Hong_Kong VARCHAR (50), Hong_Kong_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Hong_Kong_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Hungria VARCHAR (50), Hungria_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Hungria_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Mexico VARCHAR (50), Mexico_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Mexico_Gold VARCHAR (50),"
                        + "Rusia VARCHAR (50), Rusia_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Rusia_Gold VARCHAR (50),"                 
                        + "Singapur VARCHAR (50), Singapur_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Singapur_Gold VARCHAR (50),"                            
                        + "Sudafrica VARCHAR (50), Sudafrica_Oferta VARCHAR (50), Sudafrica_Gold VARCHAR (50)"

                + ")");           

        System.out.println( "Tabla creada!");


        for (Item game : games) {
            String titulo = game.getName();

            boolean isInsert;
            try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ?")) {
                ps.setString(1, titulo);

                try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                    isInsert = !rs.next();
                }
            }

            if (isInsert) { //si se cumple esta condicción significa que el juego no está incluido, con lo que lo metemos
                try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, Tipologia, Pertenece, "
                + "Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi,Pegi_USA, Descripcion_Pegi, Codigo_juego,"
                        + "Argentina, Argentina_Oferta, Argentina_Gold,"
                        + "Brasil, Brasil_Oferta, Brasil_Gold,"
                        + "Canada, Canada_Oferta, Canada_Gold,"
                        + "Colombia, Colombia_Oferta, Colombia_Gold,"
                        + "Espanya, Espanya_Oferta, Espanya_Gold,"
                        + "USA, USA_Oferta, USA_Gold,"
                        + "Hong_Kong, Hong_Kong_Oferta, Hong_Kong_Gold,"
                        + "Hungria, Hungria_Oferta, Hungria_Gold,"
                        + "Mexico, Mexico_Oferta, Mexico_Gold,"
                        + "Rusia, Rusia_Oferta, Rusia_Gold,"
                        + "Singapur, Singapur_Oferta, Singapur_Gold,"                            
                        + "Sudafrica, Sudafrica_Oferta, Sudafrica_Gold"                           
                + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?"
                        + ")")) {

                    ps.setString(1,titulo);
                    ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                    ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                    ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                    ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                    ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                    ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                    ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI_USA));
                    ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));   
                    ps.setString(10,game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL)); 
                    int contador = 11;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: countries.entrySet()) {   
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_OFFER + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_GOLD + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                    }
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            } else {
                String query = "UPDATE info_XboxOne SET Tipologia = ?, Pertenece = ?, "
                + "Nota = ?, Descripcion_Ingles = ?, Descripcion_Castellano = ?, "
                + "Pegi = ?, Pegi_USA = ?, Descripcion_Pegi = ?, Codigo_juego = ?,"
                        + "Argentina = ?, Argentina_Oferta = ?, Argentina_Gold = ?,"
                        + "Brasil = ?, Brasil_Oferta = ?, Brasil_Gold = ?,"
                        + "Canada = ?, Canada_Oferta = ?, Canada_Gold = ?,"
                        + "Colombia = ?, Colombia_Oferta = ?, Colombia_Gold = ?,"
                        + "Espanya = ?, Espanya_Oferta = ?, Espanya_Gold = ?,"
                        + "USA = ?, USA_Oferta = ?, USA_Gold = ?,"
                        + "Hong_Kong = ?, Hong_Kong_Oferta = ?, Hong_Kong_Gold = ?,"
                        + "Hungria = ?, Hungria_Oferta = ?, Hungria_Gold = ?,"                           
                        + "Mexico = ?, Mexico_Oferta = ?, Mexico_Gold = ?,"
                        + "Rusia = ?, Rusia_Oferta = ?, Rusia_Gold = ?,"                        
                        + "Singapur = ?, Singapur_Oferta = ?, Singapur_Gold = ?,"                            
                        + "Sudafrica = ?, Sudafrica_Oferta = ?, Sudafrica_Gold = ?"                          
                        + " WHERE juego = ?";

                try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
                    ps.setString(1,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                    ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                    ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                    ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                    ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                    ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                    ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI_USA));
                    ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));
                    ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL));
                    ps.setString(10,titulo);
                    int contador = 11;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: countries.entrySet()) {   
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_OFFER + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_GOLD + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                    }
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }           
}


} catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public String ConvertirObjectToString(Object Obj) {
String Str="";
if(Obj!=null){
    Str = Obj.toString();
}
return Str;
}


}
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Comment: Si el juego no está incluido y lo quieres incluir debes usar execute() en vez de executeUpdate()

Comment: Curiosamente para meter juegos no hay problema, lo que no me ejecuta es la actualización de los datos cuando los juegos ya están incluidos.

Comment: En  que momento le pasas el id al update en tu sentencia mediante ps?

Comment: En tu `UPDATE` tienes  **46** símbolos `?`... no veo que tus `ps.setString(9....); ps.setString(10...);` lleguen a `46`. **Te faltan muchas columnas por pasar al `ps`**

Comment: @A. Cedano, se las está pasando en el FOR.

JetLagFox en tu código de update tienes "WHERE juego = ?" Y no veo que tengas una columna llamada "juego", la tienes "Juego" con mayúscula. Igual y eso podría ser. Cámbialo y nos dices qué fue.

Comment: @user2930137 Noooo. Si te fijas bien, en el UPDATE antes del `for` pasa 10 valores al `ps.` y **dentro del for pasa sólo  3 valores** ¡Faltan (46-13) parámetros al `UPDATE` ! :) Y el `INSERT` creo que tiene el mismo problema.

Comment: @A. Cedano, Pasa solo tres valores pero el FOR se ejecuta varias veces seguro(Argenita, Brasil, Canada, etc), sino no tendría caso ponerlo dentro de un FOR.
JetLagFox espero un comentario sobre mi respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano user2930137 Creo que el problema puede ser a que el orden en que he declarado los parámetros no es correcto. en el update tengo puesto en la posición 10 la inclusión del título, cuando la posición 10 es para el precio de USA. Estoy ejecutando el programa de nuevo para saber si es simplemente eso, lo que pasa que tarda 2 horas, irá por la mitad.

Comment: @user2930137 Cierto, cierto... buena apreciación. De todos modos creo que el problema anda por ahí... Cuando me fallan cadenas tan largas de inserción o actualización creo una variable de cómo quedaría mi eventual cadena SQL, casi siempre hay una `,`  de más, o falta una columna, o no están en el orden esperado, etc... ¿Tarda 2 horas para ejecutarse? OMG.

Comment: @A.Cedano Es información de más de 1.000 juegos y de 12 paises distintos, 2 horas comparadas con las 10-12 horas que me va a tardar en ejecutarse cuando añada el código que tengo comentado para incluir todos los juegos...no es nada :) Es muy probable que sea ese el fallo, porque no me da ningún tipo de error, y el `INSERT` me funciona sin problemas.

Comment: No es normal que un programa tarde 2 horas en ejecutarse, a no ser que se conecte a una BD en un servidor remoto con una conexión lentísima aún así, el programa se caería dando un error del tipo `Requested Time Out`.... 1000 juegos no es nada, hoy día una BD **bien diseñada** te lee millones de registros en un abrir y cerrar de ojos.

Comment: JetLagFox, probaste haciendo el cambio que te dije? Si eso no resuelve el problema igual deberías cambiarlo. Juego != juego. Haz lo que dice A. Cedano. Imprime en consola la cadena del update y luego la ejecutas directamente en el manejador de BD. Y es impresionante que dure tanto, más bien no es normal. Se me hace raro que no te salte una exception de tiempo de ejecución o respuesta o algo así.

Comment: @user2930137 Ya está corregido, era problema a que estaba metiendo donde no era el título del juego.

Comment: Agrega el error que te genera por favor

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado no veo el `UPDATE` por ningún sitio, pero por otro lado te recomiendo no reinventar la rueda. Usa [`INSERT` con `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) o bien [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) para insertar un nuevo dato y en caso de existir que lo borre y guarde con los datos nuevos.

Recuerda que [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) ejecuta consultas SQL que no devuelven ningún registro, no están haciendo una consulta `UPDATE` por sí misma. Si tu SQL es un `INSERT`, será únicamente una inserción de datos.

Comment: Ya puedes perdonar, me he confundido de código. He editado la primera pregunta poniendo el código correcto.

Comment: Mi respuesta se mantiene válida. Prueba uno de los métodos que te propongo, usa el campo `juego` como índice único para que funcionen ambas opciones.

Comment: El problema es que si uso `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` no me estaría funcionando bien tal cual tengo ahora la tabla. Uso una columna ID, que es la key, y estaría buscando por el nombre del juego. Es decir, que en si tendría que eliminar la columna `ID`y poner a la columna del nombre del juego como key primaria...es por eso que no usé `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: No es necesario borrar la clave primaria para agregar un índice único.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql te facilita lo quieres hacer con la siguiente clausula:

```
INSERT INTO tabla(id,col1,col2) VALUES (1,'VALOR 1','VALOR 2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = 'VALOR1', COL2 = 'VALOR2';
```

Otra cosa, para actualización, inserción o eliminación de la base de datos, debes utilizar el método **executeUpdate(String sql);**